# Acceder a JSON de respuesta en AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Intento acceder a los valores de la respuesta que recibo mendiante AJAX pero no soy capaz. El JSON que recibe la función en el `success` creo que está bien, pero cuando accedo a sus elementos estos tienen valor `undefined`.

Si lanzo en la consola

```
console.log(data);
```

Obtengo este resultado:

```
{
    "id": 83,
    "error": 0,
    "msg": "evento creado"
}
```

Pero sin embargo

```
console.log(data.id);
```

obtengo `undefined`.

**AddEvent.php**

```
$resp["id"]    = '';
$resp["error"] = '';
$resp["msg"]   = '';

try {

    $event         = new Event($title, $start, $finish, $description, $type, $color, $customer);
    $resp["id"]    = $event->newEvent();
    $resp["msg"]   = 'evento creado';
    $resp["error"] = 0;

} catch (MyException $e) {

    $resp["error"] = 1;
    $resp["msg"]   = $e->getMessage();

}

echo json_encode($resp);
```

**JavaScript**

```
if (btnSave.html() == "guardar evento") {
    e.preventDefault();
    //not use serialize because I need manipulate start and end
    var title = $('#event_title').val();
    //I clone 'date' because I need generate two different dates
    var finishDate = date.clone();
    var start = addTimeToDate(date, $('#event_start').val());
    var end = addTimeToDate(finishDate, $('#event_end').val());
    var description = $('#event_description').val();
    var type = $('#event_type').val();
    var customer = $('#event_customer').val();
    //prepare send to AJAX
    var send = {
        "title"       : title,
        "start"       : start,
        "finish"      : end,
        "description" : description,
        "type"        : type,
        "customer"    : customer,
    };

    $.ajax({
        url     : "addEvent.php",
        type    : "post",
        data    : send,
        success : (function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      console.log(data.id);
                  })
    });
```

Comment: Añade a tu llamada `ajax` el parámetro `dataType` con valor `json`. También puedes usar el shortcut [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!!, llevaba un rato largo pensando en lo que podñia estar mal

Comment: De nada, un saludo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al retornar un **JSON** de algún **API** para obtener los datos que te retorna es le primer parámetro dentro de la function `success` o en este caso es una promesa y es en el `then()` lo mas normal es ponerle como clave `data` te dejo un ejemplo saludos espero ayudarte.

hay casos en que el retorno es un dato en especifico y para que el **ajax** entienda que valor a retornar cambia o agrega el

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

En caso de que retornes un **string** tienes que usar la función `parse()` y así ya puedes manipular los datos retornados.

> NOTA: Para poder usar la funcion `parse()` el string tiene que tener la estructura de un **JSON**

```
var datax = JSON.parse(data)
```

Para el ejemplo hacemos un `console.log()` de lo retornado

```
 console.log(data);
```

Y para obtener un dato dentro de el como el `title` en este caso:

```
$("p").text(data.title)//data es el retorno y title es una clave dentro de el
```

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 $("p").text(data.title)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás devolviendo un **JSON** desde tu **PHP** entonces debes indicar a tu **AJAX** el tipo de dato que va a recibir usando la opción `dataType`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "addEvent.php",
    type: "post",
    data: send,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.id);   
    }
});
```