# Json Recibido desde php no he podido colocarlo en option de un select dependiente

Tags: php, ajax, json

Este enlace me fue de gran ayuda, ahora tengo el jason en la variable pero no he podido colocarlo en el select deseado  ya que tengo uno quien me da el número de dpto y a su vez busco los grupos hasta allí todo bien me muestra en pantalla con un alert el contenido completo del json el problema ocurre cuando quiero sacar la información del json me da error undeffined([Obtener valor de select y utilizarlo en el mismo archivo php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158778/obtener-valor-de-select-y-utilizarlo-en-el-mismo-archivo-php/158814#158814?newreg=df48d797dcf9495fb52b6221ac4d8490))

```
<?php
  include('Conexion_Abrir.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<meta content="IE=edge,requiresActiveX=true" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/logo.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablasmostrar.css">
<link href="css/Estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Combobox.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>SISTEMA</title>
<style>
    fieldset{-webkit-border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px;}
    fieldset legend { background: #666; color:#fff; padding: 6px;  font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['Descri'];
echo "<br />";
?>
<center>
<!-- tabla actualiza -->
<form name="actualiza" method="post" action="Contenido.php">
<table width='50%' border='0' class='ventanas' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
    <td  colspan=2 class='tabla_ventanas' height='10' align='center'>Actualiza Divisas</td>
</tr>
<tr><td  colspan=2><div id="resultado"></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
&nbsp;
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Datos del Usuario</strong></legend>
<center>
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><input type="hidden" name="txtId" id="txtId"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre: </td><td><input type="text" disabled name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" class="CajaTexto" size="40" value = <?php echo $_SESSION['Descri']?> x-webkit-speech="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>RIF/CI: </td><td><input type="text" disabled name="txtCI" id="txtCI" class="CajaTexto" size="40" value = <?php print $_SESSION['CodUser'] ?> x-webkit-speech="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Direccion: </td><td><textarea disabled name="txtDireccion" id="txtDireccion" class="CajaTexto" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Desde: </td><td><input type="date" enabled name="Desde" id="Desde" class="CajaTexto" size="15" value ="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"  x-webkit-speech="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<body>
<div align="center">
<font size=3 color=#02a7c6 face=Segoe>
<b>Departamento:
<p>Seleccione Dpto.:
<!-- <select  name="Departamento" id="Departamento" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="CajaTexto"> onchange="showData()" -->
<!-- <form action="Grupo.php" method="post"> -->
<select  name="Departamento" id="Departamento"  class="CajaTexto">
<option size=3 value="0" >Seleccione:</option>
<?php
$sql      = "SELECT * FROM MA_DEPARTAMENTOS ORDER BY C_DESCRIPCIO";
$rs       = sqlsrv_query($conexion10,$sql);
if($rs === false){
}else{
    //$Combo="";
    while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo '<option value="' .$fila['C_CODIGO'].'">'.$fila['C_DESCRIPCIO'].'</option>';
    }
  sqlsrv_close($conexion10);//echo $_POST["Departamento"];  
}
?>
<!-- PRUEBA CON AJAX Y JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="../jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(){ 
    //Detectar el cambio de opción del proveedor
    $(document).on('change','#Departamento',function(){
      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en los usuarios
      // $('#usuarios option').each(function(){
      //   $(this).remove();
      // });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var Dpto = $(this).val();
      alert(Dpto);
      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( Dpto && Dpto != '' ){
        alert("Pasó Por Aquí! Dpto");
        alert(Dpto);
        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          async: true,
          url: 'BuscaGrupo.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca a los usuarios
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {Dpto:Dpto}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          datatype:'json',
         
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria
           // console.log(respuesta);
           // console.log(respuesta.cod);
           //$('#Grupo').view(respuesta);
            alert(respuesta);
            alert("Pasó Por Aquí! RESp");
           
            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta ){
              var i = 0;
             
              alert("Pasó Por Aquí! IF");
              //Agregar opción por default a usuarios
              $('#Grupo').append('<option disabled selected>Seleccione:</option>');
            //  $(respuesta).each(function(i,v){
            //    Grupo.append('<option value="' + v.cod + '">' + v.desc + '</option>' );
            //    alert("Pasó Por Aquí! each");
            //  })
              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              // $('#Grupo').change(function(){
              //   $('#Grupo option:selected').text());
              // });
                //for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {
                //  $(respuesta).each(function(cod,desc){
                //    Grupo.append('<option value="' + desc.cod + '">' + desc.desc + '</option>');
                //  })
            for (i; i <1;) { 
               // foreach(respuesta as $obj)
                alert("Pasó Por El for");
                alert(respuesta.length);
               alert(respuesta);
                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de usuarios
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].cod + '">' + respuesta.data[i].desc + '</option>';
                alert(i);
                $('#Grupo').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert("No Pasó Por Aquí! IF Success");
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert("Pasó Por Aquí! ERR");
            alert( err );
          }
        })
      }

    });

  });
</script>

<!-- FIN PRUEBA CON AJAX Y JS -->
</select>
</font>     
</p>
<!-- </form> -->
<br>
<!-- Grupos -->
<font size=3 color=#02a7c6 face=Segoe>
<b>Grupo
<p>Seleccione Grupo:
<select name="Grupo" id="Grupo">
<option size=3 value="0">Seleccione:</option>

</font> 
</select>   
</p>
<!-- Fin Grupos -->
</div>
</body>
<td colspan=3 align='center'><img src='imagenes/HRline200.png' width='335'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height='50' colspan=3 align='center'><button class="clean-gray" onclick="actualiza();"> Actualiza </button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</fieldset>
</td>
<td>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr/></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
</form>
</html>
```

> este es mi código html aquí llega bien el json el problema lo tengo cuando quiero colocarlo en un select... disculpen si está algo desordenado lo estoy haciendo desde mi teléfono ya que no tengo internet en la pc.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
//Agregamos el encabezado para retornar JSON
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('Conexion_Abrir.php');

  //Declaramos un arreglo que vamos a retornar
  $arr = array();
    //Validamos que la información que llega no esté vacía,
  //armamos un arreglo asociativo que tendrá la información de retorno
  if( empty($_REQUEST['Dpto']) ){
    $arr = array(
      'success' => false,
      'message' => 'El valor llegó vacío',
      'data' => null
    );
  }

  else{

    //Asignamos el valor que llegó a una variable y hacemos la consulta
    $id = $_REQUEST['Dpto'];
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$id')</script>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM MA_Grupos  WHERE C_DEPARTAMENTO ='".$id."' ORDER BY C_DESCRIPCIO";
    //$rs       = sqlsrv_query($conexion10,$sql);
    //Validamos que la consulta esté bien creada
    if( !$rS = sqlsrv_query( $conexion10, $sql )){
      $arr = array(
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Consulta mal formada',
        'data' => null
      );
    }

    else{
      //Validamos que la consulta regrese información
      if($rS === false){
      //if( sqlsrv_num_rows( $rS ) <= 0 ){
        $arr = array(
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'La consulta no regresó registros',
          'data' => null
        );
      }

      else{
        //Recorremos la variable para extraer la información y la metemos
        //en un arreglo asociativo que se usara en el Javascript
        $data = array();
        while ($rw = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rS )) {
          $data[] = array(
            'cod' => $rw['c_CODIGO'],
            'desc' => $rw['C_DESCRIPCIO']
          );
        }

        //Agregamos la variable al nodo data y ponemos todo exitoso
        $arr = array(
          $data
          // 'success' => true,
          // 'message' => 'Consulta exitosa',
          // 'data' => $data
        );
        //Limpiamos la el resultado y liberamos memoria
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($rS);

       //Cerramos la conexión
       sqlsrv_close($conexion10);
      }         
    }
  
  }
  //Retornamos el arreglo con un formato de tipo JSON
  echo json_encode( $arr );
 // print_r($data);
?>
```

Y este es el código PHP que utilizo lo he editado guiándome por el enlace que he colocado de Alberto

Comment: Hola descomenta la línea `console.log(respuesta)` e incluyes esa 'salida' en la pregunta. Así podemos saber como te está llegando para sugerir su aprovechamiento

Comment: Saludos. Te falto indicar el error en donde sale da un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124042/acceder-a-json-de-respuesta-en-ajax

Comment: Saludos estimados, el error se presenta cuando quiero recorrer el json en el for para colocarlo en un select, así viene el json : {"0":{"0":{"cod":"0801","desc":"AGUA MINERAL"},"1":{"cod":"0803","desc":"BEBIDAS PASTEURIZADAS"},"2":{"cod":"0811","desc":"BEBIDAS RECONSTITUYENTE"},"3":{"cod":"0810","desc":"BEBIDAS REFRESCANTES"},"4":{"cod":"0802","desc":"BEBIDAS SIN REFRIGERACION"},"5":{"cod":"0818","desc":"CONCENTRADOS"},"6":{"cod":"0819","desc":"CONCENTRADOS CONGELADOS"},"7":{"cod":"0825","desc":"HIELO"}}} con este formato viene desde php con JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Comment: Saludos así llega el json sin el JSON_FORCE_OBJECT: [[{"cod":"1102","desc":"CARNES"},{"cod":"1103","desc":"ENDIABLADOS"},{"cod":"1121","desc":"FRUTAS A GRANEL"},{"cod":"1122","desc":"FRUTAS CONGELADAS"},{"cod":"1123","desc":"FRUTAS EMPACADAS NASA"},{"cod":"1120","desc":"FRUTAS ENLATADAS"},{"cod":"1125","desc":"FRUTAS ENVASADAS"},{"cod":"1124","desc":"GRANOS ENLATADOS"}]]

Comment: Saludos en estas lineas se produce el error ```   //for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {
                {
                //    Grupo.append('<option value="' + desc.cod + '">' + desc.desc + '</option>');
                //  })
            for (i; i <1;) { 
                alert("Pasó Por El for");
                alert(respuesta.length);
let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].cod + '">' + respuesta.data[i].desc + '</option>';  $('#Grupo').append(option); ``` hay líneas en comentario ya quebte estado probado a ensayo y error

Answer (score 0):

aquí coloco la solución para quienes están o estuvieron en la misma situación ```
Luego del success:function(respuesta) le hice parse

```
var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);
```

Y así pude recorrer el array Gracias!